# Compute average of the same column prefix from df.corr result

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a new dataframe from correlation dataframe (computed using df.corr):

```
   A    B1    B2  C
A  1    0.1  0.2  0.4
B1 0.1  1    0.5  0.8
B2 0.2  0.5  1    0.7
C  0.4  0.8  0.7  1
```

How to I compute the average of cell with the same prefix (for example B1,B2 in this case)?

Comment: So the average of 4 cells?

Comment: It might be helpful to share the expected output, so it's crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a column grouping (axis=1) on the first letter of each column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 'B1': [0.1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.8],
 'B2': [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 0.7],
 'C': [0.4, 0.8, 0.7, 1.0]})

df = df.groupby([x[0] for x in df], axis=1).mean()

print(df)
```

Output

```
     A     B    C
0  1.0  0.15  0.4
1  0.1  0.75  0.8
2  0.2  0.75  0.7
3  0.4  0.75  1.0
```